# Программное отключение экрана android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Пытаюсь программно отключить экран
использую функцию:

```
public void turnOffScreen(){
// turn off screen
Log.v("ProximityActivity", "OFF!");
mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "tag");
mWakeLock.acquire();
```

}

но она не работает 
ошибок тоже не выдает
есть ли альтернативные варианты решения задачи ?

Comment: Перпишн же указан  `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK`?

Comment: Да, указан конечно

Comment: Попробуйте, что нибудь из этого должно помочь.  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294917/android-java-turn-screen-off

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340150/android-l-5-x-turn-on-off-mobile-data-programmatically

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535101/how-can-i-turn-off-3g-data-programmatically-on-android

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693682/turn-off-device-programmatically

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically) описано несколько разных способов. Для поиска можете использовать запрос `android turn screen off programmatically`.